# nginx rewriting query parameter value

Tags: parameters, nginx, url-rewriting

How do I write the config in nginx to rewrite the following url: `domain.com/index.php?page=home` into `domain.com/index.php?page=m-home`

Comment: I also want to know how i can fix this :) Do already have the best solution? Please met me know

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($args ~* (.*)(page=home)(.*)){
set $args $1page=m-home$3;
}
```

Comment: Should this require a rewrite too?

Answer (score -1):

```
rewrite ^/index.php?page=m-(.*) /index.php?page=$1 last;
```

Comment: huh? have you noticed I need "m-" in the page parameter?

Comment: looks like you revised the question. then i added m-, it's simplel. you should noteice the REGEX of group (.*) to achive your best match.

Comment: You are doing the opposite

Answer (score -1):

```
rewrite ^/index.php?page=(.+?)&(.*)$ /index.php?page=m-$1&$2 break;
```